# I am trying to create a letter that will merge with a database and input the "name" from my database into the "name" field of the letter

Tags: microsoft-word

Would this be done in Access or can it be done from Word or do I have to merge from another source?

Comment: Both. You make the letter in Word, and then pull your data form Excel or Access.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to an Access databases, Excel documents and I believe SQL databases.

I prefer to use Excel, simply create a table with a line for each record and then use the Step by Step Mail Merge Wizard under Start Mail Merge on the Mailings tab in Word to connect to the spreadsheet.

[Hopefully this will help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-HA102809678.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What the others say, but you can also use a table in a Word document as your data source if you prefer. Put the column name(s) in the first row, and data in rows 2 and onwards. In fact, you do not have to use a table, but it may be simpler to do so.